# How to string format OptionParser() help message?

Tags: python, linux, terminal, optparse, optionparser

How to string format OptionParser() help message? It seems to ignore the new line character? Please see below code.

```
parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("--s", dest="s", type="string", help="first line \n second line")
```

Intention:

```
current output:
.... first line \n second line

expected output:
.... first line 
     second line
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [displaying newlines in the help message when using python's optparse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961160/displaying-newlines-in-the-help-message-when-using-pythons-optparse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might I suggest [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html)?

I'm not sure if this is supported in OptionParser, but I would suggest using a triple quote
i.e:

```
parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option('--s',
                  dest='s'
                  type='string'
                  help='''
With triple quotes I can directly put in anything including line spaces.
\n will appear as a string rather than a newline.''')
```

argparse example:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--s',
                  help='''first line
second line''')
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.s
```

Comment: i'm seeing that \n is ignored no matter what quotes i use... I need to create newlines with \n

Comment: The `\n` will be ignored. Simply by pressing the `Return` character on your keyboard will put a newline in there for you.

Comment: wow... why did I not think of that... I was thinking there is viable solution and begin manually creating my own arguement parser

Comment: Try using argparse. The link I provided has some great examples.

Comment: The triple quotes are just another way of inserting an `\n` into the help text string.  They don't help with the original problem (with either parser).  The `argparser` formatter_class has to be changed to `RawTextHelpFormatter`.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `Lib/optparse.py` file.

```
class HelpFormatter
    def format_option
    ...
    if option.help:
        help_text = self.expand_default(option)
        help_lines = textwrap.wrap(help_text, self.help_width)
        result.append("%*s%s\n" % (indent_first, "", help_lines[0]))
        result.extend(["%*s%s\n" % (self.help_position, "", line)
                       for line in help_lines[1:]])
```

In other words, your `help` string is passed through `textwrap.wrap`.  A quick test of that function shows that it removes embedded `\n`, and splits the line as it sees fit.

As with `argparse`, you can customize your help by subclassing `HelpFormatter`, and rewriting selected methods such as this one.  For example, you might get want you want by replacing that `textwrap` call with `help_lines = help_text.splitlines()`.  You loose the automatic wrapping, but gain control over the appearance of the help.

`OptionParser` takes a `formatter` parameter.  `IndentedHelpFormatter` is an example of customized formatter class.

The `argparse`, `RawTextHelpFormatter` class does just such a change, replacing a `wrap` call with a `splitlines()`.